# Getting message "The authenticity of host can't be established" but host is in known_hosts

Tags: ssh, known-hosts

I've just tried to connect to an SSH server to which I've connected before, but I'm getting this message:

```
The authenticity of host '[HOST]:PORT ([IP]:PORT)' can't be established.
D25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

However, I've checked in `known_hosts` and the entry is there:

```
HOST,IP ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SOMELONG/STRING
```

(I've checked that HOST and IP match)

Any idea what could be the reason? Is there any way to debug this issue and see why it doesn't find the known_hosts entry?

If that makes a difference it happened after I've upgraded to macOS 12.3, although I don't know for sure if it's related.

Also is it safe to answer that I want to continue connecting?

**Edit:** I've just found out SSH no longer tries to load my existing `known_hosts` file, and instead tries to load a `known_hosts2` file:

```
debug1: Authenticating to HOST:PORT as 'USER'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/USER/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
```

Any idea where it gets this known_host2 file config value from, and why it suddenly changed? I've checked `~/.ssh/config`, `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d` and can't find any reference to this known_hosts2 file.

Comment: ssh has for decades tried _both_ known_hosts and known_hosts2 (not host2) automatically; usually only the former exists. Your problem is that you have a known key of type ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 but **you are receiving a key of type ed25519 which is a different type and a different key** not the known one.

Comment: Verify your keys by following this tutorial https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/verifying-the-authenticity-of-remote-host/